# Scroll View no Android Studio, pergunta Básica

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Tenho uma dúvida bem básica, como vejo o conteúdo que está abaixo do ScrollView visível no próprio editor? Uma vez que o conteúdo que ultrapassa a resolução selecionada não aparece?

Comment: Como assim no próprio editor?

Comment: Por exemplo, criei um Textview que ultrapasse a tela "visivel" do celular, ou seja, eu teria que rolar a tela para baixo no celular para ver o restante do texto certo?, como faço isso no próprio editor?

Comment: Junior, dar scroll com o mouse dentro do ScrollView no `Layout Editor` não funciona? Pelo menos a partir da versão 2.2 é possível fazer isso. Achei esse gif como exemplo: https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/4u2flb/android_studio_22_preview_5_allows_you_to_scroll/?st=iwoym5vb&sh=3c272ee0.

Comment: Atualizei aqui e deu certo, valeu cara!

Answer (score 2):

Como comentei, basta atualizar para qualquer versão superior do Android Studio 2.2.

Nessa versão já está implementado o scroll do conteúdo do `ScrollView` dentro do Layout Editor.